# Why this integral is calculated incorrectly？

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
Input:
Integrate[1/y - Floor[1/y], {y, 0, 1}]
N[Integrate[1/y - Floor[1/y], {y, 0, 1}]]
Output:
Integrate[1/y - Floor[1/y], {y, 0, 1}]
0.418638
```

The above code is my input and output when calculating an integral.
But the correct result is not that.
The correct result is:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]\right) \mathrm{d} x &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{x}-k\right) \mathrm{d} x \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\ln (k+1)-\ln k-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) \\
&=\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty}\left(\ln (n+1)-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\cdots-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\
&=1-\gamma
\end{aligned}$$
The number $\gamma$ here is Euler's constant, approximately equal to 0.577

Comment: You did not post the complete output – Mathematica gives you a warning that the integration did not converge! You can use a different method, for example ``NIntegrate[1/y - Floor[1/y], {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]`` which will give a more accurate result (0.422956, which is accurate to 0,04 %). However, note that your function is very oscillatory, and integrating such function may require special methods. There are already [several questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnumerical-integration%5D+oscillatory) here on StackExchange about this topic.

Comment: In addition to using a "LocalAdaptive" `Method` as recommended by Domen, increase recursions: `MinRecursion -> 9` and `MaxRecursion -> 20`